# Simple Swift 3 logging solution

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to implement logging in my application. I want it to be simple and to **not affect performance**.

I've looked into Apple's newly released logging APIs:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/os/1891852-logging

I did implement a quick example in my app, but I couldn't see the output unless I ran in "Test" mode. Is there any way to view this output in the normal "Run" mode?

Also I need to be able to log the entries to file so that I review them later when I connect the device to my mac. Eventually I'm going to have it upload this file to my server, when a debug option is checked in my app.

Thanks.

Comment: Checkout [this](http://abizern.org/2015/02/01/debug-logging-in-swift/)

Comment: Ah thanks. I've seen this, and wasn't a fan. I've since written my own. I'll put it on github soon and link it below.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, so I'm hoping you've had some success.

Comment: @WayneHenderson yeah, I've just uploaded it to Github: https://github.com/notoriousturtle/DebugLog - It does the job. Feel free to contribute and fix any bugs you encounter :)

Comment: I added it as the answer, but @MartijnPieters decided to delete it because I wouldn't paste an essay of code as the answer - it's the people's loss now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**Printer**](https://github.com/hemangshah/printer) a new logging experience.

It has the function to save logs to a file for later use.

**Usage:**

*To log a success message:*

```
Printer.log.success(details: "This is a Success message.")
```

**Output:**

```
Printer ➞ [✅ Success] [⌚04-27-2017 10:53:28] ➞ ✹✹This is a Success message.✹✹
[Trace] ➞ ViewController.swift ➞ viewDidLoad() #58
```

You should read out [this](https://github.com/hemangshah/printer#all-logs-for-use) for the exact usage.

**Disclaimer**: This library has been created by me.